# How to sort a 2D list of strings by length in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list in python which contains first and last names of different people. It looks like this :
`teachers=[["Rachelle", "Goodyear"],["Mike","Anderson"], ["Jeremy","Smith"]]`
And I want to sort them by the length of their last name.
I've tried different solutions but it always sort by their first name ... Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you tried (formatted code), and what didn't work (error traceback). This is the minimum expected for getting help on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
sorted_teachers = sorted(teachers, key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
```